# Cellar installation on Felix

Tags: apache-felix, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

I have written an OSGI container based on Felix Framework and have implemented felix remote shell implementation. 
I want to now add the cluster support. Can I install Cellar and related bundles (cellar feature which is available on Karaf) on to my custom OSGI container ? How can I do that ? Any link to a blog post or a simple hint to do so, will be very much appreciated.
I tried installing the bundles manually, but they all depend on Karaf Shell which my container does not have and I don't need it in my situation. (my remote shell implementation with commands that I have implemented are sufficient)

Thanks 
Abhijit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you neglect the shell bundles for cellar. All of the Apache Karaf Cellar bundles are modular enough to work without shell. You can take a look at the features descriptor for cellar and just leave those out.